# Launcher Icon is not Shown in Oreo 8.0/8.1

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-8.0-oreo

> **Explanation:**
>
> I have a working app in google play market. Everything works fine in
>   android versions from 4.0-7.0.
>
> **Case:**
>
> When the client downloaded it on his Android 8.0 (Oreo) a launcher
>   icon did not seem to show instead android's default launcher icon is
>   showing!!
>
> **Question:**
>
> Anyone who has encountered such issue? I need any hints to solve it since it seems weird because I have all 4 typed .png icons in mipmap folder.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, I also faced the same issue in Android Oreo.

> 1) Add your images by adding in Image Vector

[image]

Comment: Now I will try and let you know whether it will work or not.

Comment: Yes. it did work. If I had an .svg icons would it still be a problem @Nirav Joshi?

Comment: Best and easiest way to do it.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-and-the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-launcher-icon-154f9267f98e

Comment: How to open this asset studio ? I mean can you please tell teh steps to open assests studio ?

Comment: File -> New - > Image Asset  @B.shruti

Comment: Thanks @Nirav Joshi

Comment: when i'm tapping the next button screen is shaking, its not creating can you please help me

Answer (score 34):

This might not be the ideal solution. But deleting the directory named mipmap-anydpi-v26 will resolve the issue if you have correct icons in relevant folders.

Comment: Not sure why this works. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 23):

I was having the same problem make sure you have set drawable or mipmap to **icon** **attribute** as well as **roundIcon attribute** under application tag in your Manifest file

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">

</application>
```

This might resolve someone's issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't create a right `ic_launcher_round` icon.

Answer (score 2):

None of the previous answers worked for me. I discovered my project had a file `app/src/main/res/drawable-v24/ic_launcher_foreground.xml` while another project didn't. That was the reason the other project **did** have an icon in Android 8 and this project not. When I removed the `drawable-v24` folder I got my icon back!

Answer (score 1):

Try restart your mobile and install app on device

Comment: Weird, but this was the only solution that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a .png image in the Image Asset tool to generate launcher icon.

Answer (score 0):

**`Android -> Project -> App - > src -> res`**

**`right-click on res then -> new -> image asset -> inside add image set as your logo ratio`**

[image]

[image]