# ic_launcher in Oreo (API Level 26)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a question!!!

why my android project lose its **launcher icon** in android 8 (API 26) ??:(

My co-worker get project from *Git* and this problem occurred.

I try to solve it , change icon quality , clean and rebuild project and ...

please help me I don't have any idea for this problem :|

project Launcher icon in  API 26:
[image]

Comment: can u share your manifest file ans also check that you have added **`android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"`**

Comment: see this :-https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669288/2919483

Comment: You can generate launcher icon by File->new->Image Asset and select the launcher images and you can adjust or can trim in manifest file you can set what Mr.roshan says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

You need to define the launcher icon manually

Use a `.png` `image` in the `Image Asset tool` to generate `launcher icon`.

In your  `manifest` set `application` `icon` as follow

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">
</application>
```

Also make sure that `ic_launcher` icon is available in your `drawable` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add Round icon also for app
in mipmap required round icon 
project Launcher icon in API 26:

```
   <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    > </application>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the method **Legacy only**

[image]

I hope help