# App launch icon is not shown in proper way on Android 8.0 Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

The launch icon is not display well on devices with OS 8.0/8.1 Oreo.
I make everything like here [Launcher Icon is not Shown in Oreo 8.0/8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938643/launcher-icon-is-not-shown-in-oreo-8-0-8-1), but the result is that:

[image]

Can someone help with that?

Comment: Would you please try to remove app from device, remove build folder from app and then run again?

Comment: just remove **ic_launcher_round** from all the mipmap folders and try reinstalling it after removing it.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I did what you say, but the result is the same. Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: @RahulKhurana I tried your suggestion too, but doesn't work

Comment: Had you remove **android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"** from androidManifiest.xml file ??

Comment: Are you tried this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669288/5167909

Answer (score 3):

After nougat there are two layers for an icon one is foreground and one is background What you need to do is Right click on the app icon then go to new -> image asset -> choose launcher icons -> then there you can choose background and foreground layer then finish the process and in manifest as follows -

```
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

you will find both the icons in mipmap folder in your resources

Comment: Welcome Brother

Answer (score 1):

May be the resolution of the icon is not proper. You can generate icon with proper resolution and other properties try [this](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=0&foreground.space.pad=-0.1&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=1&backgroundShape=circle&effects=none&name=ic_launcher). Here you can choose and edit app icons as per android icon specifications.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was just to upload a svg file for the foreground layer and put some color for the background layer. 
Now the launch icon is shown correct.
Hope this can help to someone else ;)