# My app icon is not showing on some devices

Tags: android, google-play

I just published my app on play store and I notice that some Samsung device does not display the icon of my app. They assert the default icon of android studio.  Have you an idea what can cause that? i'm confused

```
<application 
android:name=".MyApp"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
 .... 
</application>
```

Comment: Check your all mipmap folder. maybe one of them does not contain the right png image.

Comment: How it shows? Like Default app icon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try This;

```
File -> New -> Image Asset -> Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy)
```

For more information;
https://proandroiddev.com/android-adaptive-icons-are-easier-than-you-think-3c66be2dd4dd

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

Answer (score 10):

Remove this line..

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Answer (score 7):

My issue was solved by restarting the phone.

Answer (score 4):

I thing some device had oreo and pie OS that why device does not show the correct app icon.Now you can delete ic_launcher_round and ic_launcher from mipmap-anydpi-v26

please check this link [Launcher Icon is not Shown in Oreo 8.0/8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938643/launcher-icon-is-not-shown-in-oreo-8-0-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I noticed my mipmap folder is missing but if I search the icons in the project they are there. So I created a mipmap folder manually **New > Android resource directory > Mipmap**. Then I generated the image asset for the icons again.