# Recently used app icon when app is minimized for newer android devices

Tags: android

Running on an android API 29 emulator, if you minimize an app and view the minimized list of apps, they each have an icon associated with them:

[image]

in my example here, there's a round chrome icon associated to google chrome at the top of the card.

My question is : how do you set this icon, what is it called and when was it introduced (I'm basically looking for documentation on it)

I've tried setting `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` in the manifest but it doesn't seem to apply.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: did you tried these solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938643/launcher-icon-is-not-shown-in-oreo-8-0-8-1

Comment: i didn't because our launcher icon works, but this specific icon is not displayed, but i'll have a look at it maybe i missed an icon, thank @zakjma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it uses adaptive icons i.e items with foreground and background set inside an xml

eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
   <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

Set this adaptive icon as your rounIcon then

Have a look at this link, it should answer your query

[Adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)

Comment: sure np :) i had the exact same issue a while back so ... :D

Comment: Adaptive launcher icons are also used in shortcuts, the Settings app, sharing dialogs, and the overview screen.   ---- exact words in the link :)

Comment: keywords for google search :   android recents screen app icon in api 28 and above

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio - generate launcher icon as image assets. it will generate all supported format for background and foreground including launcher icon. To generate icon right click on drawable folder -> New -> Image assets.

post this check the xml files -

1. Under mipmap ->  ic_launcher_round ->ic_launcher_round.xml (anydpi-v26) - there should be entry like this -

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
      <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
   </adaptive-icon>
   ```
2. Under mipmap -> ic_launcher -> ic_launcher.xml (anydpi-v26) - there should be entry like this -

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
          <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
    </adaptive-icon>
   ```