# How to create a circular icon for my Android app?

Tags: android, drawable, android-launcher

I just swapped my android launcher icon(just learned how).  I noticed MANY icons on my android are circular and I am wondering do I have to get an image done like that OR is there way I   can have the launcher put the icon(a png with transparent background) and draw a circle for the launcher somehow?  (this would be easier that fooling around in some drawing tool as well).

In the app I used CircleImageView for contacts which did the circle but that was in java, and android launcher is xml so not sure if I can use CircleImageView?

Comment: is it related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568443/recently-used-app-icon-when-app-is-minimized-for-newer-android-devices) ?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use [adaptive icons](https://medium.com/google-design/understanding-android-adaptive-icons-cee8a9de93e2) instead of a single image to allow Android to adjust your icon. Essentially this is defining a background drawable and a foreground drawable, and Android will do the rest.

If you right click your `res/drawable` folder in Android Studio, then select `New` -> `Image Asset`, you will see the following wizard. This will let you easily create launcher icons that work in all shapes.

[image: Android Studio image asset wizard]

For further information you may find the [official Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) helpful, as well as [Nick Butcher's excellent guide](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/implementing-adaptive-icons-1e4d1795470e).