# Change android app icon which shows on open app with Android Studio

Tags: android

I am creating an app in Android studio. I want to change the app icon which shows when my app is opened. Please refer to the following image to understand my problem:

[image]

The icon is properly showing for my apk file and app icon. But my opened app shows the default icon.

**What I done yet:**

I added the app icon in my AndroidManifest.xml:

android:icon="@drawable/myappicon"

android:roundIcon="@drawable/myappicon"

I also added Go to menu File* → New → Image Assets → select launcher icon → choose image file etc

Still my opened app showing default app icon please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568443/recently-used-app-icon-when-app-is-minimized-for-newer-android-devices

Answer (score 0):

**I got the solution!!**

Copy icon file from file window and paste your icon file in Android Studio --> app --> res --> drawable folder!!

Go to Android Studio --> app --> res --> mipmap --> ic_launcher --> ic_launcher.xml and make changes on "myicon" place!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/myicon"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/myicon"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```